# PHP Global Variables across .php files

Tags: php

I have two files that get loaded on a page (body.php and footer.php).

In body I have:

```
<?php global $pageName = "foo";?>
```

In footer I have:

```
<?php echo $pageName;?>
```

However, it echo's out nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: there is no need for the `global` keyword here, the variable was already defined in the global scope. did you include the footer page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to define the global variable as a global. 
You can use this piece of code in your body:

```
<?php $pageName = 'foo'?>
```

And this piece of code in your footer:

```
<?php global $pageName; echo $pageName //$pageName from body.php ?>
```

An alternative is to create a page.php file where you put your data like this:

```
<?php
// (Inside page.php)
$pageName = 'foo';
require('header.php'); // Use $pageName in header.php without global
require('body.php'); // Use $pageName in body.php without global
require('footer.php'); // Use $pageName in footer.php without global
?>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you. My question was probably unclear - but this was the behaviour I was aiming for and has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The global scope only counts for the file where the varibale lies in. What you could do is to [include](http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php) the `footer.php`, then your code will work.

body.php:

```
<?php $pageName = "foo"; //No need for the global, the varibale is already in the global scope
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Will echo out "foo"at the end.

[In the official documentation you can read about variable scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

**EDIT according to the comment**

You could set set variable to the [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

So your body.php would look like:

```
<?php
session_start(); //IMPORTANT, this must be the first action you do. 
$pageName = "foo"; //No need for the global, the varibale is already in the global scope
$_SESSION['pageName'] = $pageName;
?>
```

Your footer.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); //IMPORTANT, this must be the first action you do. 
echo $_SESSION['pageName'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this loads the whole footer.php page (which I load later). Is there a way to just pass the variable through please?

Comment: @user1149620 you're loading the footer page at a different time!? well that makes sense then why its not working. do a google search on how to use `$_SESSION`

Comment: @user1149620 Are you including the footer.php later into the body.php?